# Changing the title of a UIButton from a UILabel or UITextFiled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to know change the title of a UIButton from a UILabel or UITextFiled. For example, If I enter text into a UITextField and tap a button that says "enter" or something similar, another button's title will change to the text in the text field. Another example if I enter text into a text field and click "enter" in one view controller and click "next" to go to another view controller, a button in the later view controller will have the title of the text in the text field from the previous view controller. I currently don't have code to show what I have becasue nothing I have found has helped me at all. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[button setTitle:label.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Break down the problem into pieces. Do you know how to handle pressing "Enter" for a text field? Do you know how to update a button's label?

Comment: Take a NSString property object in next view and pass textfield value to that object. and use that string as your button or label text in viewdidload of next view.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a stab:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// When user taps on your enter button in your first view controller
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
-(void)enterButtonPressed
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

    // set the button title in your second view controller
    [vc2.otherButton setTitle:self.textField.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // show second view controller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Ok I have a method called done where once it's called, two labels change their text to the text in the text field. I also have another method that once called, changes views. Which method should I put the first two lines of code from the method you provided in or should I just put the lines of code in the viewDidLoad method in the second viewController?

Comment: When you're about to show the second page, set the title of the button before you push it onto the navigation stack. So I guess in your case, that would be your "another method" that "changes views". That way, you can be more confident the title of the button doesn't get changed somewhere unexpectedly as it happens immediately before you show the next view controller.

Comment: I put what you said in the method that changes views, but it still doesn't work. The code makes sense but it hasn't worked for me yet. I'll continue to see if I did anything wrong on my part.

Comment: Well, maybe if you edit your question and include the relevant parts of the code, we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  // get the instance of your button
    if(textField.tag == matchedTag){
     [[button titleLabel] setText:@"xyz"];  // or below call 
     [button setTitle:@"xyz" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
}
```